# cxf local transport JAX_WS

Tags: cxf, jax-ws

I Am using CXF framework to implement JAX_WS soap web service. I want to make use of local transport to call a webservice in another web service with out using actual endpoint. any examples?

```
JaxWsServerFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsServerFactoryBean(); 
        factory.setServiceBean(new LocalTransportSample_Service().getLocalTransportSamplePort()); 
        factory.setAddress("local://hello"); 
        factory.setTransportId(LocalTransportFactory.TRANSPORT_ID); 
        Server  server = factory.create(); 
                JaxWsProxyFactoryBean proxyFac = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean(); 
        proxyFac.setAddress("local://hello"); 
       proxyFac.getClientFactoryBean().setTransportId(LocalTransportFactory.TRANSPORT_ID); 
        LocalTransportSample exc = proxyFac.create(LocalTransportSample.class);       
       return exc.hello("I am from local transport");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JaxWsServerFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsServerFactoryBean(); 
        factory.setServiceBean(new LocalTransportSample_Service().getLocalTransportSamplePort()); 
        factory.setAddress("local://hello"); 
        factory.setTransportId(LocalTransportFactory.TRANSPORT_ID); 
        Server  server = factory.create(); 
                JaxWsProxyFactoryBean proxyFac = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean(); 
        proxyFac.setAddress("local://hello"); 
       proxyFac.getClientFactoryBean().setTransportId(LocalTransportFactory.TRANSPORT_ID); 
        LocalTransportSample exc = proxyFac.create(LocalTransportSample.class);       
       return exc.hello("I am from local transport");
```

Comment: Step1. Register services which needs to be consumed as local//